# Not able to run Custom query in Tableau -Athena

Tags: connection, tableau-api, amazon-athena

I am getting error when I run custom queries in tableau. [Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYXr3.png)

The connection is working with the Anthena, I can get the data from Athena to Tableau, the joins are working in tableau BUT when I try to run a custom query it is giving me the error (please see the pic), even for a very simple query.

I have installed java 8 & moved AthenaJDBC42 to Tableau Driver folder but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you authenticate with Athena?

Comment: Authenticating with Amazon Athena Credentials: Server, Port, S3, KeyID, Access Key. My colleague is using the same credentials but not facing any such issue. I factory reset my PC, tried  AthenaJDBC41, JDBC4.1, JDK7 combinations & AthenaJDBC42, JDBC4.2, JDK8. Nothing is working

Comment: resolved the issue by using older Athena JDBC version. AthenaJDBC42_2.0.8